# iOS 9 custom URL scheme not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, applinks

My web application is making use of iFrame to launch a App using custom URL scheme.

With the latest release iOS 9 this has stopped working.

On going through articles online, I have some understanding now that Universal Links are way to go about it or else we can use below hack/code to still launch the app(this results in a alert message asking user to Open/Cancel the call, which doesn't look nice).

window.location = app://

Wanted to check with experienced people here, if there is any other possible way to resolve this as I am reluctant to change the app to support Universal Links for now.

Comment: The simplest solution is not to use an IFRAME. I can't tell if this is an option for you.

Comment: Read this http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes you now have to declare the custom schemes in your apps plist