# URL Schemes Not Working For native Maps App In iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, ios9, url-scheme

I need to open native iOS maps app from my app using below code:

```
 NSString *urladdress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@",@"Texas,US"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urladdress];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

And I have also configured .plist as shown in below image

[image]

When I run my code I found following error in my console as shown in below image

[image]

I have searched a lot of similar links in stack overflow like

[iOS 9 safari iframe src with custom url scheme not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891777/ios-9-safari-iframe-src-with-custom-url-scheme-not-working)

[iOS 9 custom URL scheme not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894984/ios-9-custom-url-scheme-not-working)

[Google Maps URL scheme not working on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686515/google-maps-url-scheme-not-working-on-ios-9)

but I am not able to solve my issue.

I would like to request you all to solve my query or show me the right path whether I am going on wrong direction. IF any example in stack or in somewhere else which I have missed to refer please let me know.

Comment: AFAIK `LSApplicationQueriesScheme` is not required for native maps app. Probably there is an error in the formed URL. You could try examples from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) to see if really apps app is not invoked. eg: http://maps.apple.com/?address=1,Infinite+Loop,Cupertino,California

Comment: Vin, Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: FYI - `LSApplicationQueriesScheme` is only needed to call `canOpenURL:`, not `openURL:`.

Comment: Vin, Thanks for your quick reply. Could you post your comment through answer so i can upvote?

Comment: rmaddy, Thanks for your reply and kind suggestion.

Comment: @JekilPatel did you get it solved using http://maps.apple.com/?address=1,Infinite+Loop,Cupertino,California ?

Comment: @Vin Yes I got the solution from your comment, thanks. Please post your answer so i can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by `rmaddy`

> `LSApplicationQueriesScheme` is only needed to call `canOpenURL:`, not
>   `openURL:`

Even if you were using `canOpenURL:`, it would not be required to add `LSApplicationQueriesScheme` in the `Info.plist` for invoking the native maps app.

There seems to be a problem with the parameteres of the URL that you are forming to invoke Maps app. Try using one of the URLs mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html).

For example, you could use [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+95014,+USA/@37.332112,-122.0329646,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x808fb5b6e7b4b9fb:0x697a4332574f50d9).